# Does property precedence matter in css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

While looking at the new `bootstrap.css` file for bootstrap version 3,i came across this snippet

```
hr {
  height: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
       box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

On another split view,i had `normalize.css` which had this snippet

```
hr {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
}
```

I found this comment for the `normalize.css` snippet

```
/**
 * Address differences between Firefox and other browsers.
 */
```

Comparing the two,the height property comes first in bootstrap and last in normalize.Does this make matter in any way?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not.

It only matters, obviously, when it's the same property or a sub-property, like setting `padding-left` first and then setting `padding`.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time if you have a conflict in styles the issue will come down to specificity.

A general rule of thumb when declaring your Css is to declare properties with the least specificity needed to style your elements.

So let’s look at three things that control which css rule applies to a given html element:

- Specificity Calculations
- Inheritance
- The Cascade

Bold-Answer: **NO**, it does not matter.

Take a look at [Specifics on CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)